# ¿Cómo puedo ver la ayuda de Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter, anaconda, ipython

Estoy viendo un tutorial en el cual muestran paneles con información sobre las librerías, y no encuentro información sobre como mostrarla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que puedas ver la ayuda de Jupyter deberías hacer  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> mientras estés ubicado en la función que querés ver.